# Why are these log statements not printing?

Tags: kotlin, debugging, logging, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I'm building an object detection application (in Kotlin, for Android). The application uses CameraX to build a camera preview and Google ML to provide machine learning expertise. Just for reference; I used [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/preview) CameraX documentation and this [this](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android) Google ML Kit documentation.

I'm currently attempting to print `Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess" + it.size)` to my IDE console in order to determine if `.addonSuccessListener` is actually running. If it does, it should print something along the lines of `onSuccess1`. However, this isn't the case. Infact, it isn't even printing the Log statement from the `.addOnFailureListener` either, which really confuses me as I'm not even entirely sure the objectDetector code is even running. What really puzzles me is that I have relatively completed the same project in Java and have not faced this issue.

I did have someone point out that within my `YourImageAnalyzer.kt` class, **if** `mediaImage` is null, then I won't see anything logging. However, upon my own debugging (this is actually my very first time debugging), I was unable to find out if my first sentence of this paragraph is true or not. I suppose this issue may provide a lead into how I'll resolve this issue, and also learn how to properly debug.

Here is my `YourImageAnalyzer.kt` class, and I will also add the code for my `MainActivity.kt` class below as well.

### YourImageAnalyzer.kt

```
private class YourImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {
        val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
        if (mediaImage != null) {
            val image =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)

            val localModel = LocalModel.Builder()
                    .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite")
                    .build()

            val customObjectDetectorOptions =
                    CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                            .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
                            .enableClassification()
                            .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                            .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(3)
                            .build()


            val objectDetector =
                    ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions)

            objectDetector           //Here is where the issue stems, with the following listeners
                    .process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.i("TAG", "onSuccess" + it.size)
                        for (detectedObjects in it)
                        {
                            val boundingBox = detectedObjects.boundingBox
                            val trackingId = detectedObjects.trackingId
                            for (label in detectedObjects.labels) {
                                val text = label.text
                                val index = label.index
                                val confidence = label.confidence
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.e("TAG", e.getLocalizedMessage()) }
                    .addOnCompleteListener { it -> imageProxy.close() }
        }
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            bindPreview(cameraProvider)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

    }

    fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
        val previewView = findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.previewView)
        var preview : Preview = Preview.Builder()
                .build()

        var cameraSelector : CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build()

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

        var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you verify if the analyze() method is called or if the mediaImage is not null? You could add some log to check that.    If you can see logs telling mediaImage is not null, how many times do you see it? If your camera is setup correctly, you should see it very frequently since the camera is running.

Comment: You could also check your adb log to see if there is any other error. I notice that you are using a custom model. If the model is invalid, the ML Kit detector will fail to create.  In that case, you should see some log mentioning "MlKitException"

Comment: @Steven I indeed just have verified to see if the `analyze()` method has been called or not only to find out that it indeed has NOT been called. This leads me to wonder why this is the case. However, the camera is running perfectly fine.

Comment: In this case, it is mostly a CameraX setup issue. You can try adding the android-camerax tag to your question to seek more help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-camerax

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding your ImageAnalysis use case. Something in the line of:

```
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .setOutputImageFormat(ImageAnalysis.OUTPUT_IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
    .build()
```

and then;

```
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, YourImageAnalyzer())

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis, preview)
```

Also a suggestion as a bonus:
You should get your `LocalModel.Builder()` out of `analyze` as this is called each time an image arrives. You do not need to execute this code piece each time as it will make your analysis slower.
So move this code:

```
val localModel = LocalModel.Builder()
                    .setAssetFilePath("mobilenet_v1_0.75_192_quantized_1_metadata_1.tflite")
                    .build()
```

to just below of the class `private class YourImageAnalyzer : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {`.

Comment: Just one quick question; `executor` shows up as red, stating its an unresolved reference, so what would be the way to resolve that? Other than that, everything else checks out!

Comment: Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Comment: So I've been attempted to diagnose this for quite a while, but while all your code has indeed been implemented, the problem still stands. The log statements that I've placed in OP have still not printed. Would you happen to know the reason why?

Comment: I would move the logging to just beginning of `override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {` to see if analyze method is called at all or not. If it is printed, then your code fails somewhere after. If it is still not printed at all then it could be a small detail you might be missing. Then i would suggest you to follow this step by step tutorial: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0

Comment: After moving the logging to the beginning to see if the analyze method is called at all, it's come to my discovery that it actually hasn't been called all along. But yes, I will follow this tutorial in order to resolve this problem, thank you!

Comment: Upon following the tutorial and implementing solutions I've found around the internet, your link to your answer played a fundamental role in solving this problem!

Comment: I want to ask why the codelab you shared had worked, but the official documentation doesn't?

Comment: Not really sure on that one. Might be related to versions used. Glad it helped.